CMake Error at C:/Users/35523/Desktop/AAR_API_TEST/aar_testing/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/cmake-utils/ReactNative-application.cmake:42
CMake Error at C:/Users/40366/Desktop/AAR_API_TEST/aar_testing/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/cmake-utils/ReactNative-application.cmake:42 (add_library):
Syntax error in cmake code when parsing string
whenever i tried to build or sync up Gradle in react native project this error is occurring ...
Erron showing in ReactNative-Application.cmake
in this add_library(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${input_SRC}) line
